# Хочу узнать, правильно ли я использовал тире в предложении

Tags: тире, приложение

> Интересно написан конфликт между двумя другими важными членами отряда
> S.T.A.R.S.: специалисте по оружию — Барри Бёртоне, и лидере команды —
> Альберте Вескере.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попытаюсь максимально сохранить авторское предложение — сделать только необходимые изменения.

• Вместо "написан" лучше использовать глагол "описан".

• Конфликт между (кем? — нужен творительный падеж) *специалистом* и *лидером*.

• Ни тире, ни запятая не нужны.

• Имена, если я правильно поняла, такие: Барри Бёртон, Альберт Вескер.

> Приложение, стоящее перед именем собственным, обособляется только в том случае, если имеет добавочное обстоятельственное значение: ***Упрямец во всём,** Илья Матвеевич оставался упрямцем и в учении* (Коч.)...
> Но без добавочного обстоятельственного значения: ***Поручик царской армии** Василий Данилович Дибич пробирался из немецкого плена на родину* (Фед.).

Получаем:
*Интересно описан конфликт между двумя другими важными членами отряда S.T.A.R.S.: специалистом по оружию Барри Бёртоном и лидером команды Альбертом Вескером.*

[Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111) (п. 2.5)

Answer (score 0):

```
Попытаюсь максимально сохранить авторское 
предложение — сделать только необходимые изменения 
(из принятого ответа).
```

**ВМЕСТО ВСТУПЛЕНИЯ**

Сохранять авторское предложение важно в **художественных текстах**, когда многословность может быть **авторским** приемом для раскрытия образа. Но в текстах **информативного** содержания  принцип информативности должен быть на первом месте. ***Пиши — сокращай!*** **Лишние слова** только мешают прочтению и пониманию сказанного. именно поэтому я предлагаю **другую запись** с таким же **(авторским!)** содержанием.

**В качестве варианта:**

*В конфликтной ситуации оказались **два других важных члена отряда** S.T.A.R.S. — специалист по оружию **Барри Бёртоне** и лидер команды  **Альберте Вескере**.*

Здесь желательно использовать имена **в начальной** форме, иначе они сложно читаются. Дополнительные знаки **не нужны** (приложение перед именем собственным), **уточняющего** значения нет.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149343/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.